How do you use gcs signed URL to do multipart upload?
Using GCS, I want to generate a link on the server and pass it to the clients. The clients use it to upload a large file, hence the multi part upload.
I'm able to initiate the multipart upload which gives me the uploadId (ref: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-multipart). But when I try to upload the parts using the signed url which I used to make the POST request on, or generate new signed urls for each part with PUT, I get a 403 with SignatureDoesNotMatch code with reason The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret and signing method.
The service account used here at sa.json should have all the permissions because it is added as a storage admin to the project itself.
Here's the python code I'm using.
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import requests

def generate_upload_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration, method):
  """
  Generates a signed URL to initiate a multipart upload.

  Args:
      bucket_name: Name of the bucket to upload to.
      object_name: Name of the object to upload.
      expiration: Expiration time for the URL in seconds.

  Returns:
      A signed URL for initiating the multipart upload.
  """
  # Assuming the service account JSON key is in the same directory with the name 'sa.json'
  service_account_key_path = 'sa.json'
  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_key_path)
  client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
  bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
  upload_url = blob.generate_signed_url(
      version="v4",
    #   content_type="application/octet-stream",
      query_parameters={
        "uploads": "",
      },
      method=method,
      expiration=expiration,
      credentials=credentials,
  )
  return upload_url

def do_post_on_signed_url(upload_url):
  """
  Sends a POST request to the signed URL to initiate the upload.

  Args:
      upload_url: The signed URL for initiating the upload.
  """
  response = requests.post(upload_url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"})
  response.raise_for_status()

  print(f"Response: {response.text}")

  # parse uploadid from response example response
  #   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><InitiateMultipartUploadResult xmlns='http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/'><Bucket>pr-cache-bucket-0</Bucket><Key>randomfile.tar.gz</Key><UploadId>ABPnzm5hfCDjy44Aa2WDHPxGL9kDyJ3GwtFvToGhVYgNul2PiIOcGI8siu_HjXHeYRkbPxo</UploadId></InitiateMultipartUploadResult>
  upload_id = response.text.split("<UploadId>")[1].split("</UploadId>")[0]
  return upload_id


# Send this upload_url to your client-side application
def upload_file_in_chunks(url, upload_id, filepath, chunk_size=1024 * 1024):
  """
  Uploads a file in chunks using the provided URL.

  Args:
      url: The signed URL for uploading data chunks.
      filepath: Path to the file to upload.
      chunk_size: Size of each upload chunk in bytes (default: 1MB).
  """
  with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
    chunk_counter = 1
    for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(chunk_size), b""):
      print(f"Uploading chunk {chunk_counter}...")
      signed_url = generate_upload_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration, "PUT")
      url = f"{signed_url}&uploadId={upload_id}&partNumber={chunk_counter}"
      headers = {"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}
      if chunk:
        response = requests.put(url, data=chunk, headers=headers)
        print(f"response: {response.text}")
        response.raise_for_status()
        chunk_counter += 1

  # After all chunks uploaded, complete the upload (not shown here)

filepath = "randomfile.tar.gz"
# Example usage
bucket_name = "pr-cache-bucket-0"
object_name = "randomfile.tar.gz"
expiration = 3600  # 1 hour

upload_url = generate_upload_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration, "POST")
upload_id = do_post_on_signed_url(upload_url)

# merge upload_id with upload_url
upload_url = f"{upload_url}&uploadId={upload_id}"

print(f"Upload URL: {upload_url}")

upload_file_in_chunks(upload_url, upload_id, filepath)

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not sure about the issue because I'm not using my own signing program, I'm likely missing something.

Can you check with the suggestions shared in this Stackoverflow Link.

Yeah I checked that, I'm sending the methods in the signature generation request. Also added the content-type but it doesn't seem to work for the upload operation.

The 403 errors for signed URLs are often caused by users signing the wrong canonical string. I'll recommend reviewing these Link1 and Link2  for further information on signed URLs.
